# How do I make my web-api work with my controller using service class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

So I'm working on my web application in .net core 2.1. I've used a Api template and I am trying to make my controller do a HttpGet, where I want to list all items from my database.

My DbProvider in this case is a service-class.

I've followed this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

#### My controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValueController : ControllerBase
    {
        DbProvider _dbProvider;

        public ValueController(DbProvider dbProvider)
        {
            _dbProvider = dbProvider;
        }



        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Dto>> ListAllItemsAsync()
        {
            return await _dbProvider.ListAllValuesAsync();
        }

}
```

#### My service class (the provider)

```
  public class DbProvider
    {
         DbRepository _repository;

        public DbProvider(DbRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Dto>> ListItemsAsync()
        {
            return await _repository.ListAsync();
        }
}
```

#### My Startup-file:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            var connString = "database-connectionsting-hardcoded-for-now";
            services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connString));
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddTransient<DbProvider>();

        }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
              
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else app.UseHsts();
    
                app.UseDefaultFiles();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseMvc();
    
    
            }
```

I am getting error code 404, and in Postman I can't get any results.
I expect to get some json values from my database, so I can see that everything is running smoothly.

What am I missing?
I can do a regular HttGet-method, and it does work. Like this:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index() //This works
    { 
        return Content("Sucsess! ");
    }
```

Comment: 404 is "Not Found". What did you use as url?

Comment: https://localhost:44339/ @Fildor

Comment: Should be something like `http://localhost:44339/api/value`

Comment: @Fildor tried that too, and still got 404 error

Comment: Try https and/or UseMvcWithDefaultRoute instead of UseMvc

Comment: What is in your `ConfigureServices` ?

Comment: @Fildor updated to show you.

Comment: @AdamJachocki I've tried that. And it didn't change the result.

Comment: DbRepository is somehow missing in the DI Setup, isn't it?

Comment: @Fildor yeah, that is my guess at the moment. I've injected the DbRepository using the constructor injection, same thing with the DbProvider. This is what is recommended for .net core 2.1 and later according to documentation... Not sure how to solve this right now

Comment: `services.AddTransient<DbRepository>();` ? Not sure if order matters, I'd try before `services.AddTransient<DbProvider>();`, but anyway, I wouldn't expect a 404 if this is the actual problem. I'd expect more like a 500...

Answer (score 1):

I am closing this question, since my problem has to do with dependency injection and my layered architecture. I've discovered this after some reading in different blogs.
Thank you all for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you must use this url:

```
localhost:44339/api/value/ListAllItemsAsync
```

Comment: When using [Route("api/[controller]")] on ValueController, you must use [HttpGet("[action]")] on Action Mthod